# O que quer dizer a licença MIT?

Tags: google

> > Copyright (C) [year] [copyright holders]
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
>   a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
>   "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
>   without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
>   distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
>   permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
>   the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
>   included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

Estou utilizando um template que peguei em um site e dentro dele veio a a licença acima. Queria saber se com esses termos eu preciso referenciar o copyright dentro do meu template ou apenas manter o arquivo de licença em algum lugar

Answer (score 4):

A licença é permissiva e considerada equivalente a BSD Simplificada sem a cláusula de endosso. Porém, seu texto é bem mais explícito ao tratar dos direitos que estão sendo transferidos, afirmando que qualquer pessoa que obtém uma copia do software e seus arquivos de documentação associados pode lidar com eles sem restrição, incluindo sem limitação os direitos a usar, copiar, modificar, mesclar, publicar, distribuir, vender copias do software. As condições impostas para tanto são apenas manter o aviso de copyright e uma copia da licença em todas as cópias do software.

Fonte: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licen%C3%A7a_MIT

Comment: Minha dúvida é se preciso colocar os copyrights no template (visível ao usuário)

Comment: Pelo que li nesse link que colei aí em cima, é importante manter um aviso de copyright, não necessariamente no template. Acredito que pode ser em um arquivo ou algo assim. Mas sobre isso, não tenho certeza.